# ¿Se puede pasar por parametros a una funcion su propio valor de retorno?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

hola estoy intentando hacer un filtro pero necesito que los datos de salida del filtro vuelvan a pasar por el filtro N veces es decir hasta que obtenga el dato que estoy buscando. Pero esto se puede hacer en python? necesito hacerlo con el uso de llamadas a una función filtro determinada por mi, es decir
    def filtro(x,y)
    calculos
    return (p,q)

y que luego el mismo filtro tome p,q es decir 
    def filtro(p,q)
    calculos
    return (m,l)
es posible hacer esto es python ? y si es posible? como haría para plantearlo muchas gracias..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes simplemente usar una aproximación iterativa usando un ciclo, por ejemplo con un `for` puedes hacer que se aplique `n` veces la función:

```
def foo(p, q):
    p += 1
    q += 5 
    return p, q

p = 14
q = 23
for _ in range(5): 
    p, q = foo(p, q)
```

Si el numero de iteraciones es indeterminado y depende de cierta condición usa un `while`:

```
def foo(p, q):
    print("Valor de p:", p)
    p += 1 
    return p, q

p = 1
q = 5
while p != q:
    p, q = foo(p, q)
```

Puedes crear una función que te permita ejecutar `n` veces cualquier función con un numero indeterminado de argumentos posicionales (que lógicamente pueda retroalimentarse con su propia salida):

```
def repetir(func, veces, *args):
    if not args:
        for _ in range(veces):
            func()

    elif len(args) == 1:
        arg = args[0]
        for _ in range(veces):
            arg = func(arg)
        return arg

    else:
        for _ in range(veces):
            args = func(*args)
        return args

def foo(p, q):
    p += 1
    q += 5 
    return p, q

def cuadrado(n):
    return n * n
```

> ```
> >>> repetir(foo, 4, 2, 13)
> (6, 33)
> >>> repetir(cuadrado, 4, 2)
> 65536
> ```

Comment: Estoy probando el metodo que me has dado, al parecer funciona pero tengo un problema cuando llamo el metodo dentro del for por decir 5 veces, en mi caso tengo una grafica que se sobreescribe.. es decir se plotea encima varias veces.. como haria para que se me impriman a parte las 5 versiones distintas?

Comment: @Loreisiss intenta agregar un [mcve] a la pregunta, al menos que muestre como estas creando la gráfica dentro de la función y que biblioteca usa para tal fin (p.e matplotlib) a ver si te puedo responder de forma más especifica para tu problema.

Comment: En realidad tengo varias funciones que me grafican por ejemplo:

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178735/como-imprimir-varias-gr%C3%A1ficas-en-una-misma-ventana-en-python-en-especial-si-s